# Variable substitution in script file and setting a new variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm attempting to run a command in a shell script and set a variable with the resulting process id. Stripped down to the relevant parts, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=myAppUser
PATH_TO_APP=/opt/folder/subfolder
PID=`su - $USER -c 'nohup $PATH_TO_APP/myapp --option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!'`;  
echo $PID
```

I understand that I need to use double quotes around the `nohup` command for variable substitution, but if I do, `PID` is not being set. If I use double quotes and hardcode the `PATH_TO_APP` it will execute and set `PID`. I'm guessing it's a problem with the combination of the back tick and single/double quotes.. but I'm not sure what the solution is.

Comment: Why do you need to use backticks at all? Just run the command and do `PID=$!`

Comment: In modern shell, you ought to use $(stdout emission) in stead of \`stdout emission\`

Comment: Oh, I see, you're getting the PID of the process run by `su`, not the `su` process.

Comment: Thanks for the correction/tip @LaurentG !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the command in double quotes so that `$PATH_TO_APP` will be substituted, and then escape the `$` in `$!` so it will be included literally in the argument to `su`, and then processed by the subshell.

```
PID=$(su - $USER -c "nohup $PATH_TO_APP/myapp --option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$!")
echo $PID
```

Comment: Ahh not escaping the `$` is why it wasn't working when I used double quotes. Thank you!

Comment: Right, because it was expanding `$!` in the original shell, not the subshell.